# Is there an example of a D3 live candlestick chart being updated?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, real-time, candlestick-chart

I'd like to have a candlestick chart that plots trade data from a WebSocket feed or any generated fake data in Javascript. I've looked over all the documentation and demos, but I can't find any information on how to update an existing chart data point. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

I found a great chart called Lightweight TradingView. It's open source and you can customise everything by yourself.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).